# Delegates called when there is a phone call

Tags: objective-c, iphone, delegates

I'm developing a music application which also works on background. I want to catch when there is a phone call on the phone so I can pause the music. 
I don't want to use CTCallCenter properties as it requires me to call them time to time. Also I used the following appDelegate method:

```
-(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
     NSLog(@"Phone Call!");
}
```

It works but it is called just once and it is not only for phone calls and when I click home button and the application is on background it happens and if there is a phone call after that it keeps playing!

Comment: why not look at CTCallCenter's [`currentCalls` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCallCenter/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CTCallCenter/currentCalls) only when your `applicationWillResignActive:` app delegate method is called?  That way, you don't have to keep checking.  Or do you also want to know when the current call is finished?

Comment: applicationWillResignActive: (Called when leaving the foreground state.) read the documentation here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillResignActive:

Comment: @MichaelDautermann when the application is in background and a phone call happens this delegate is not called!

Comment: @KostiantynKoval yes that's exactly why this delegate is not working for my case

Comment: b.t.w., what are you using to play the music in the background?  `AVAudioPlayer` or something else?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann AVAudioPlayer

Comment: And when a phone call comes in, the music continues to play in the background?  [According to Apple's Audio Session documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingAudioInterruptions/HandlingAudioInterruptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH4-SW30), your AVAudioPlayer instance should get paused magically by iOS.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann not but if the music starts buffering and there is a phone call and the music starts playing, the user hears the music on call. I want to handle this case